# clearing select field automatically after selecting item

Tags: vuetify.js

I can't find a way to clear the select field in method "afterselection" which is invoked after selecting an item:

template:

```
<v-select
 :items="adrlist"
 @input="afterselection"        
 ></v-select>
```

data in select:

```
const addressList = [{
"text":"Street 523, 2533",
"value":[1723455.7054408004,5923451.382843224]},
{"text":"Lala 3, 3455",
"value":[1723455.7054408004,5923451.382843224],
}]
```

vue-code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      adrlist: addressList,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    afterselection(item){
      console.log(item);
      //here I want to clear the select
    },
  },
})
```

Here's a code pen with this example:
[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRRapV)

I've tried to set the v-model to null, but this is not working.

I have researched and tried for several days now, and I really can't find a solution :-/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 11):

Just for reference, you can clear a select field in vuetify with

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.selected = null  
  })
```

the important thing is the "nextTick"! otherwise it wont be rendered...

see this codepen provided by a vuetify-dev:
[working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEEmvr)

Comment: You can achieve the same result with setTimeout(() => { this.selected = null; }, 0); putting this at the end of the event loop instead of referencing the vue render.

Comment: @VagnerGon But why would you use that hacky method rather than the Vue method specifically defined for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issues. I have several v-select components in card text block and clear btn. When i click on clear i run clear func and clear all v-select items by refs.

template:

```
 <v-card>
  <v-card-title>Filters</v-card-title>
  <v-card-text v-if="selectFilters.length">
    <v-select
      :ref="filter.id"
      v-for="filter in selectFilters"
      :items="filter.items"
      :key="filter.id"
      :label="filter.alias"
      multiple
      return-object
      clearable
      @input="selectChangeHandler($event, filter.id)"
    ></v-select>
  </v-card-text>
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn color="primary" @click="clear">Clear</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

script:

```
methods: { 
  ...
  clear: function() {
    Object.values(this.$refs).forEach(ref => {
      const vueSelect = ref[0];
      vueSelect.internalValue = [];
    });
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding ref to the component

```
<v-select
  ref="adrlistRef"
  :items="adrlist"
  @input="afterselection"        
></v-select>
```

then use the `reset` method of `v-select` component whenever you want!

```
afterselection(item) {
  if (item) {
    console.log(item);
    this.$refs['adrlistRef'].reset();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to bind to the select a v-model that is a computed property. Then it would be possible to change that value with the @input event.

Comment: Yes, you can see it there: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwPQqO?editors=1111