# Clear search box after selecting with vuetify autocomplete

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to use the [vuetify autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes) component, but I can't figure out how to clear the search box after selecting an item. I've tried to use the input event to clear the model bound in v-model, and while it does work the first time I select an item, the search box does not get cleared afterwards.

```
//App.Vue
<v-autocomplete
      // Other stuff
      v-model="model"
      :search-input.sync="searchInput"
      v-on:input="addClass">
    </v-autocomplete>\

// methods
addClass (a) { 
  this.model = ""
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide minimal verifiable example on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com)?

Comment: If you specify `clearable` this will add in a `X` on the search box which can be used for clearing. You can also specify `chip` which can be delete with backspace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clearing select field automatically after selecting item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869649/clearing-select-field-automatically-after-selecting-item)

Answer (score 21):

To achieve this you need to set your `searchInput` variable to an empty string on the `change` event. Your code would look something like this,

```html
// App.Vue
<v-autocomplete
      // Other stuff
      v-model="model"
      :search-input.sync="searchInput"
      @change="searchInput=''"
></v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Works fine, but you need to set "searchInput: null" in data().

Comment: Jetsie is right that you need to also add `searchInput` to `data()`. However, I think the initial value should be an empty string, nut `null`. This will let you know that this variable is expected to hold a string, which would not be possible to guess if the value is set to `null`.

Answer (score 12):

I have the same question as well, and tried [Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8920999/antoine-viscardi) answer with no luck.

Checked in Vue plug-in in my environment, the issue seem to be caused by the event sequence.

After event `change` emit by `<VAutocomplete>`, there are another event `update:search-input` also emit by `<VAutocomplete>`, and from the payload it seem to setting the value to what u just cleared in `change` event and so it look like you cannot clear the value.

After many try I managed to pull out one workable code which you can find the example below, which based on [Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8920999/antoine-viscardi) solution with a few changes:

1. `$nextTick` used
2. On top of the `search-input` variable, also clear the variable bind to `v-model`

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    
    data: () => ({
      searchResult: null,
      searchString: '',
      items: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      selected: '',
    }),
    
    methods: {
      itemChange(e) {
        this.selected = e;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.searchString = '';
          this.searchResult = null;
        });
      },
    },
  })
  
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>

        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="searchResult"
          :items="items"
          :search-input.sync="searchString"
          label="Search..."
          clearable
          @change="itemChange"
        ></v-autocomplete>
        <div>{{ `Selected: ${selected}` }}</div>

      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! My input was also being set by the search input update event.

Comment: I think this is more accurate answer! Thanks! It works  like charm!

Comment: this.$nextTick did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with `v-combobox` and found a simple solution. Haven't tested for `v-autocomplete` but would guess this solution will work as well.

For `v-combobox` components, reset the component's `lazySearch` value. An example looks like this:

```html
<v-combobox
  ref="el"
  :items="items"
  chips
  clearable
  deletable-chips
  multiple
  outlined
  @change="reset"
></v-combobox>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.$refs.el.lazySearch = ''
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I retract my earlier statement, this actually works (not sure what had changed on my side) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested solution, made in Vue 3 with the Composition API and with Vuetify 3:

```js
     <v-autocomplete
            ref="addClassAC"
            v-model="selectedClass"
            :items="classes"
            @update:modelValue="addClass"
        ></v-autocomplete>
```

I've added `:items="classes"` as a list to populate your `v-autocomplete`.
You are reacting on event `update:modelValue`
`update:modelValue`: Event that is emitted when the component’s model changes.
More at: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#events

I've also changed your `model` to `selectedClass`. Try not to use names that might be reserved (Vue might break without good explanation in these cases) and also use names that better describe the usage of the variable.

Here is the code in `typescript`. I've provided comments in the code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

/** selectedClass holds the selection */
const selectedClass = ref<string>();

/** addClassAC enables us to reference the autocomplete from the code. 
It is linked through `ref="addClassAC"` in the HTML code */
const addClassAC = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  const blurEvent: Event = new Event('blur');

  const addClass = (selectetion:any) => {
  console.log("[addClass]", selectetion);

  //TODO: use the selected value `selectetion` for whatever you need
  // ...

  // resetting the value of the selector after it is selected, 
  // so that the new selection can be done:
  selectedClass.value = undefined;

  // we dispatch `blur` (unfocus) event over our autocomplete component 
  // (referenced / linked between html and code):
  addClassAC.value?.dispatchEvent(blurEvent);
}

</script>
```

*JavaScript* version provided in comment.

Comment: Here is the JS version:
```javascript
import { ref } from "vue";

const selectedClass = ref();

const addClassAC = ref(null);

const blurEvent = new Event('blur');

const addClass = (selectetion) => {
   console.log("[addClass]", selection);

   selectedClass.value = undefined;
   userAdded.value?.dispatchEvent(blurEvent);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work well. After selection, it closes the menu.

Comment: @marisks, closing the menu is desired and standard behavior for autocomplete and v-select. Thie question creator did not ask for what you asked for. But what you ask for is a standard behaviour for multiple selection option and not a single one, like here

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup>

 //Variables
const usersList = ref([
 { id:1, name: "Prince", city: "ferozepur" },
 { id:2, name: "Navjot", city: "ferozepur cantt" },
]);

const search = ref(null);

//For clear search text fields
const ACRef = ref(null);
const blurEvent = new Event("blur");

watch(search, (item) => {
  if (!item) search.value = null;
  if (item && typeof item === "object") {

    //for clear search text
    ACRef.value?.dispatchEvent(blurEvent);

    let { name, city } = item;

    //check for duplicate user
    const alreadyExist = userStore.UserList.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (alreadyExist) {
      search.value = null;
      return;
    }

    //if unique user
    userStore.UserList.push({
      name: name,
      city: city,
    });
    search.value = null;
  }
});
</script>


 //Here is Template Vuetify3 Code
 <VCol cols="12" md="6">
  <v-autocomplete
     ref="ACRef"
     v-model="search"
     placeholder="Search Existing User"
     persistent-placeholder
     :items="usersList"
     item-title="name"
     return-object
   />
</VCol>
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

In Vuetify 3 you can use the property `clear-on-select` in combination with `multiple` to clear the written text.