# Vuetify 3: Clear Autocomplete after keydownEnter while keeping it focused

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to clear the v-autocomplete after the user has pressed enter, without bluring (exiting) the autocomplete.

The only (somewhat) working solution for vuefiy 3 I've found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166096/19261708) answer to a similar question (maybe even a duplicate, but it does not seem to run into the same problem as I do)

I build a solution that is as close to my project as possible [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ppzwm6?file=index.ts,index.html,package.json). As you can see, clearing the autocomplete works for the most part, but the placeholder is not shown after clear.
But since I used the blur event (which is the only way I found the clear to work, as the DOM is only updated on blur, even if I set the model to `null` beforehand) the field is not focused anymore. Even dispatching a focusIn event does not yield the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other question you linked, you'll specifically want to clear the search input text, not just the v-model.  The Vuetify 3 documentation is not 100% correct (at the time of writing this) on how this can be done.  It lists a prop just called [`search`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-search) that controls the text input, but it's actually `v-model:search`.  You can use this to clear the input during your keydown event.

```js
data() {
  return {
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    aModel: '',
    search: '',
  };
},
methods: {
  aMethod() {
    // Do Something with the Model
    let x = this.aModel;

    //Then clear input
    this.aModel = '';
    this.search = '';
  },
},
```

```html
<v-autocomplete
  :items="items"
  v-model="aModel"
  v-model:search="search"
  auto-select-first
  class="flex-full-width"
  density="comfortable"
  placeholder="test"
  @keydown.enter="aMethod"
></v-autocomplete>
```

[updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pxqmqz?file=index.html)

Comment: Thank you. If it is so easy to fix, why is it so hard to find this information....

Comment: we needed to change the event from keydown.enter to change:model-value. Now the search doesnt clear until a blur event occurs. Do you know anything about that?