# Set the vuetify v-autocomplete to a blank

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify v-autocomplete in a dialog box and it keeps the last value selected displayed.  If I open the dialog, select a name and close the dialog the next time I open it it still displays the last selected value.

```
         <v-autocomplete default="" placeholder="Type to search" :items="members" :item-text="getFullName" item-value="MemberID" :loading="loadingMembers" @change="changeMember"></v-autocomplete>
```

Is there a way that I can set it to blank when the dialog closes?  I could probably reload the entire list of items but that seems a waste of resources since it fills with 3000 names

Thanks

Comment: I think that adding `v-model="member_select"`, and after that in `changeMember()`  `this.member_select = ''` should do the trick

Comment: If this doesn't work, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871764/3226121).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can watch dialog model and set model autocomplete to null when dialog pass at false

Dialog

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
        <v-autocomplete default="" v-model="memberSelected" placeholder="Type to search" :items="members" :item-text="getFullName" item-value="MemberID" :loading="loadingMembers" @change="changeMember"></v-autocomplete>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</dialog>
```

Javascript

```
watch: {
    dialog: function (val) {
      if(!val) {
         this.memberSelected = null
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a champ--Thanks